# Extracting data within complex functions/loops using lists/arrays

Tags: python, csv

I have this block of code that does several things; I loops through files I have saved in a folder that are labeled 1-100. These files are all forecast files for a specific month (example june 2016). What this function does is read all the files and goes to previous files to conduct forecasts. I store all the values by different months. I want to see the totals for how accurate predictions were for "one month ago", "two months ago", etc. I am able to do this with the code, however I am having trouble extracting the exact values that contribute to this total using arrays/lists. The portion that does not have to do with arrays or lists work, but I am wondering how I can extract these specific numbers. I would want to use the append numbers (the list) for graphing purposes later, that is why I am extracting it, the # with ?'s indicate the list portion that does not seem to work

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

def nmonthaccuracy(basefilenumber, n):
    basefileread = pd.read_csv(str(basefilenumber)+'.csv', encoding='Latin-1')
    basefilevalue = basefileread.loc[basefileread['Customer'].str.contains('Customer A', na=False), 'Jun-16\nQty']

    nmonthread = pd.read_csv(str(basefilenumber-n)+'.csv', encoding = 'Latin-1')
    nmonthvalue = nmonthread.loc[nmonthread['Customer'].str.contains('Customer A', na=False), 'Jun-16\nQty']

    return int(nmonthvalue)/int(basefilevalue)    

N = 12
total_by_month = [0] * N
total_by_month_list [] * N #????

for basefilenumber in range(24,36):
    for n in range(N):
        total_by_month[n] += nmonthaccuracy(basefilenumber, n)
        total_by_month_list[n].append(nmonthaccuracy(basefilenumber,n)) #????



onetotal = total_by_month[1]
twototal = total_by_month[2]      
#etc
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running your code by initializing `total_by_month_list` as

```
total_by_month_list  = [[] for _ in range(N)]
```

Without your data, it's currently speculative. What I understood is that `total_by_month_list` should be a list of 12 sublists.

Comment: Worked beautifully! Thank you

Comment: Hi, this code works for certain ranges by not others for some reason, an example of an error i get is: KeyError: 'the label [Jan-16\nQty] is not in the [columns]'
I am unsure why this works sometimes and not other times, and I have attatched an image of a dummy csv file. Thanks!